# How to compare list in Python?

Tags: python

I have one list

```
a = [1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.1, 4.2, 5.1, 7.2, 9.2]
```

I want to compare this list with other list but also I want to extract the information regarding the list content in numeric order.All other list have the elements that are same as `a`.

So I have tried this

```
a = [1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.1, 4.2, 5.1, 7.2, 9.2]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print dict(zip(a,b))

a1=[2.1, 3.1, 4.2, 7.2]
```

I want to compare a1 with a and extract dict values `[3, 5, 6, 8]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just loop through `a1` and see if there is a matching key in the dictionary you created:

```
mapping = dict(zip(a, b))
matches = [mapping[value] for value in a1 if value in mapping]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.1, 4.2, 5.1, 7.2, 9.2]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a1 = [2.1, 3.1, 4.2, 7.2]
>>> mapping = dict(zip(a, b))
>>> [mapping[value] for value in a1 if value in mapping]
[3, 5, 6, 8]
```

However, take into account that you are using *floating point* numbers. You may not be able to match values exactly, since floating point numbers are binary approximations to decimal values; the value `2.999999999999999` (15 nines) for example, may be presented by the Python `str()` function as `3.0`, but is *not equal* to `3.0`:

```
>>> 2.999999999999999
2.999999999999999
>>> str(2.999999999999999)
'3.0'
>>> 2.999999999999999 == 3.0
False
>>> 2.999999999999999 in mapping
False
```

If your input lists `a` is sorted, you could use the [`math.isclose()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) (or a backport of it), together with the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to keep matching efficient:

```
import bisect
try:
    from math import isclose
except ImportError:
    def isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
        # simplified backport, doesn't handle NaN or infinity.
        if a == b: return True
        return abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)

result = []
for value in a1:
    index = bisect.bisect(a, value)
    if index and isclose(a[index - 1], value):
        result.append(b[index - 1])
    elif index < len(a) and isclose(a[index], value):
        result.append(b[index])
```

This tests up to two values from `a` per input value; one that is guaranteed to equal or lower (at `index - 1`) and the next, higher value. For your sample `a`, the value `2.999999999999999` is bisected to index `3`, between `2.1` and `3.0`. Since `isclose(3.0, 2.999999999999999)` is true, that would still let you map that value to `4` in `b`.

Comment: Peters Thanks.The numbers in the list are result of the execution of the FORTRAN code,formated with f11.5.So I think the simple version would suffice!

Comment: Right, if you have *strings*, then you skirt around the issue quite nicely.